# Xamarin Forms 5 VS Debugger Odd Behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms 5 application that is having issues being debugged via Visual Studio.

The application has a root view with tabs and each has a `ListView` control. The application runs fine without any issues when started without debugging.

When debugging it seems that the `ListView`s are continually re-creating the cells, the descendants count just keeps going up indefinitely. To the point where the UI is unusable in any meaningful way due to the connection being swamped and the CPU continually hit.

It behaves this way when running either Android or iOS, hardware or simulator.

I've just loaded the exact same projects and solutions into `JetBrains Rider 2021.3` and debugging using Rider works flawlessly, using both simulators and hardware.

The only common denominator is the Visual Studio debugger.

At this point I'm not entirely sure how to address the issue with debugging via Visual Studio. Are there any configuration options that would be worth experimenting with to try and solve this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Unfortunately this is proprietary and would take quite some time to pull apart to get into a state where I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include your visual studio and xamarin forms version.

Possible issue : On vs you can change hot reload option in tool -> Option -> Hot reload. In the xamarin forms section, try to change the option from "Only change XF 5.0" to "Full Page".

*note : the english name of those option might not be exact (my vs is in another language).*